# HOW IS A PROGRAM EXECUTED?

Tags: c++

Once an exe is loaded in memory, is the content present in that exe file directly executed by the processor or the OS does it? I mean, is the binary present in exe simplified again by OS for machine level usage?

Comment: This question might get a little more traction here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/. The short answer is: no, binary files are not "simplified again;" they are executed directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .exe file contains op codes directly executable by the processor.

Comment: And data, and relocation information, and symbols and probably a bucketload of other stuff. Probably not all of that is loaded int _memory,_ but it's usually in the _file._

Comment: thanx @Didier this was the answer i actually wanted to read.

Answer (score 0):

For a C++ program, the compiler produces a combination of data and code in the executable image.  The OS loader arranges to put that into specific memory addresses in the program address space, then asks the CPU to call the code at known "entry point" (there may be such a pointer for each dynamically loaded library (.so / .dll) as well as the entry point for `main()`.  The executable code produced by the compiler will target the CPU models on which the code may be run.

If an attempt is made to execute the code on another CPU architecture, it will generally fail, although it's possible for an OS to do whatever it likes including detect executables compiled for another CPU and put some kind of emulation or recompilation layer in place.  This would be very much the exection though.